# Select many columns based on lowest value from multiple columns (ms access)

Tags: ms-access-2003

I searched through google but all in vain, might be due to my search query.

I have a table like given below

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| LocalID | ASIN      | Price | Shipping | Total | Currancy |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       |B01MSMCN13 | 95.99 | 3        | 98.99 |  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 2       |B01MSMCN13 | 100   | 0        | 100.0 |  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 3       |B01MSMCN13 | 104.71| 9.61     | 114.32|  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 4       |B01MSMCN13 | 124.81| 8.95     | 133.76|  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 5       |B073WDMZVT | 139.99| 0        | 139.99|  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 6       |B073WDMZVT | 159   | 0        | 159.0 |  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 7       |B073WDMZVT | 179   | 0        | 179   |  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Problem:**

I want to take all columns based on the lowest price + shipping

The Result I want like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| LocalID | ASIN      | Price | Shipping | Total | Currancy |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       |B01MSMCN13 | 95.99 | 3        | 98.99 |  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 5       |B073WDMZVT | 139.99| 0        | 139.99|  GBP     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried many queries but couldn't get the desired results.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: From Review: Can you please EDIT your answer and provide the queries you have tried so far? Please avoid posting comments to your own question in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min func and group by

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table t
WHERE Total = (SELECT MIN(Total)
               FROM Table t2
               WHERE t.ASIN = t2.ASIN
               GROUP BY ASIN)
```

Comment: But I don't want only "Total" Column, did you read my question and the desired result I want. Can I achieve by your suggested query?

Comment: @MehboobAfridi Updated my answer